# CSV Import Script Not Functioning in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created the following script. But it will not function and i cannot figure out why I followed to the tutorial on google but the script keeps timing out. Any help on how to fix this would be much aprriciated.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Update HIPAA", functionName: "importHIPAA"}, 
                        {name: "Update Harassment", functionName: "importHarassment"} ];
  ss.addMenu("Update Scores", csvMenuEntries);
}
function importHIPAA() {
  var fileName = "59156.csv";

 var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      break;
    }
  }
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("HIPAA");
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}
function importHarassment() {
  var fileName = "105921.csv";

 var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      break;
    }
  }
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Harassment");
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}
// http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm
// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;


  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }


    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }


    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
}
```

Comment: Why this unaccept ? the answer is still right since you use it in your other post ???

Answer (score 0):

try your script without this typo :

```
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){
```

should be   `while (arrMatches == objPattern.exec( strData )){`

Equality in a condition is double =

Comment: Thank You but now I get the following error: The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 23)

Comment: what is line 23 ? is it `sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));`  ?
  If so the problem comes because `csvData[i].length` is =0 and it cannot be 0... use a condition before this line  : `if( csvData[i].length >0){ ...}`

Comment: After adding the condition the script runs with out an error however the data does not import.

Comment: can you add a few Logger.log(...) to check intermediate data ? or if the csv file doesn't contain personal data share it with me ?

Comment: try       Logger.log(csvFile)
on line 16

Comment: I can share it with you. what is your email

Comment: your script is now working (at least first part, you'll have to complete the second fct.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the issue anymore but just in case
change  var files = DocsList.getFiles(); for  var files = DocsList.getAllFiles();

should work fine, I did the test

elMedex